# Quadratic extensions of function fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, splitting-field

Let $F = k(t_1,\dots,t_r)$ be the function field in $r$ variables of a field $k$, and let $F'$ be a quadratic extension of $F$.

Does there exist a quadratic extension $k'$ of $k$ such that $F' = k'(t_1,\dots,t_r)$?

I have tried the following: we can write an element of $F'$ as $\alpha + u \beta$ with $\alpha,\beta \in F$ and $u\in F'\setminus F$ such that $f(u) = 0$ with $f$ polynomial of degree two with coefficients in $F$.

Now, since $\alpha,\beta$ are rational function in $t_1,\dots,t_r$ we can write $\alpha + u \beta$ as a rational function in $t_1,\dots,t_r$ whose coefficients are of the form $\alpha_i + u\beta_i$ with $\alpha_i,\beta_i\in k$. Furthermore, evaluating $f$ in some fixed $t_1,\dots,t_r$ we se that $u$ is a root of a degree two polynomial with coefficients in $k$. So $\alpha + u \beta \in k'(t_1,\dots,t_r)$ with $k' = k(u)$.

Is this correct? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What if $k$ were algebraically closed?

Comment: In that case my argument would imply that $k' = k(u) = k$ and so $F' = F$. In other words this would mean that $F$ does no have non trivial quadratic extensions. But then what is wrong with my argument?

Comment: Did you mean $F' \cong k'(t_1,\dots,t_r)$ instead of $=$ and $[k':k]\le 2$ instead of $[k':k]=2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not true in general. The field $k$ can be algebraically closed in $F'$, and so there is no such an extension.
For example: for $char(k)\neq 2$, take $F=k(x)$ and $F':=F(y)=k(x,y)$ with $y^2=p(x)$, where $p(x)$ is an irreducible monic polynomial over $k$. We have $|F': F|=2$ and $F'=F(y)$, but $k$ is algebraically closed in $F'$.

> Furthermore, evaluating $f$ in some fixed $t_1,…,t_r$ we se that $u$ is a root of a degree two polynomial with coefficients in $k$

The element $u \in F'$ is also a function that depends on $t_1,...,t_r$, so you can't just calculate the function $f$ on $t_1,...,t_r$ in $f(u)=0$.